# Как лучше шифровать ключи с последующей расшифрацией в базе

Tags: php, хеширование, пароль

такой вопрос возник.
Есть у меня таблица с api_key ключами от разных сервисов, я хочу их шифровать в базе, но когда достаю из базы мне нужно их расшифровывать.

Нашел способ - XOR шифрование, подставляю туда свой ключ который лежит в файле и он шифрует а потом расшифровывает данные.

```
function strcode($str, $passw="", $salt = ''){
   $salt    = !empty($salt) ? $salt : "Dn8*#2n!9j";
   $len     = strlen($str);
   $gamma   = '';
   $n       = $len>100 ? 8 : 2;

   while( strlen($gamma)<$len )
   {
      $gamma .= substr(pack('H*', sha1($passw.$gamma.$salt)), 0, $n);
   }

   return $str^$gamma;
}

# Крипнуем
$txt = "Hello XOR encode!";
$txt = base64_encode(strcode($txt, 'daseqws'));

# Декрипт
// $txt = "CgYHv4PxOGXvOOzhBY/mM5M=";
// $txt = strcode(base64_decode($txt), 'daseqws');
```

В таком случае моя задача выполнена.
Если сольют базу - то там будут кракозябры, которые не расшифровать без ключа с которым закриптовали.

Но может есть еще какие-то способы есть? 
Буду благодарен за подсказки!

Comment: Ключ от XOR-шифрования подберут очень быстро. (Хотя gamma это затруднит, но, думаю, не очень сильно)

Comment: Вы пароль собираетесь шифровать?

Comment: Если пароль шифровать, то зачем его расшифровывать. Просто намертво шифруете через `sha256`, а потом в базу заливаете хэш. При проверке, просто шифруете введеный пользователем пароль таких же `sha256` и потом сравниваете два хэша: `хэш базы === хэш инпута`

Comment: @Mully перечитайте вопрос ещё раз, речь не о паролях, а о api_key

Comment: @andreymal, не увидел api(

Comment: После первого вашего коммента мне увидел)

Comment: @andreymal интересно как тогда решить вопрос, у Вас не возникало такой ситуации?)

Comment: @user190134 брать любую книжку по криптографии и изучать и использовать алгоритмы, проверенные временем и сообществом

Comment: Лучше используйте функции вроде openssl_encrypt / decrypt с алгоритмами вроде AES

Comment: а в чем прикол от вашего шифрования? если вас взломают, люди в 99% случае получат доступ сперва к вашим скриптам а потом к БД, а раз получили доступ к скриптам, у них не будет пробелм найти алгоритм расшифровки. С паролями кстати другая ситуация - нам не нужны реальные пароли юзеров, поэтому и храним хэш, и сравниваем с хэшем

Comment: @Manitikyl есть же и Иньеккции и дырки, когда сливают только базу